# What's the smart way to aggregate data?

Tags: r, regex, aggregate

Suppose there is a dataset of different regions, each region a subset of a state, and some outcome variable:

```
regions <- c("Michigan, Eastern",
    "Michigan, Western",
    "Minnesota",
    "Mississippi, Northern",
    "Mississippi, Southern",
    "Missouri, Eastern",
    "Missouri, Western")

set.seed(123)
outcome <- rpois(7, 12)
testset <- data.frame(regions,outcome)

                 regions outcome
1     Michigan, Eastern      10
2     Michigan, Western      11
3             Minnesota      17
4 Mississippi, Northern      12
5 Mississippi, Southern      12
6     Missouri, Eastern      17
7     Missouri, Western      13
```

A useful tool would aggregate each region and add, or take the mean or maximum, etc. of outcome by region and generate a new data frame for state. A sum, for example, would output this:

```
                state    outcome
1             Michigan       21
3             Minnesota      17
4             Mississippi    24
6             Missouri       30
```

The `aggregate()` function won't solve this problem. Is there something else in R that is built for this? It seems like `grep` could be used to generate the new column "states" as part of an application specific program. Seems like this would already be out there somewhere though.

Comment: There only tool that magically understands the particulars of your specific data is you. Create the additional, more meaningful columns and use `aggregate` (or something else).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this isn't straight forward is that the structure of your data is not consistent, so you couldn't build a library simply for it.

Your `state, region` column is basically an index column, and you want to index across part of it.  `tapply` is designed for this, but there's no reason to build in a function to do it automatically for this specific scenario.  You could do it without creating the column though

```
tapply(outcome,gsub(",.*$","",testset$regions),sum)
```

The index column just replaces the `,` and everything after it, leaving the index column.

PS: you have a slight typo in your example, your data.frame should be

```
testset <- data.frame(regions,outcome)
```